Check for duplicates in a column, while excluding a sub-string
I am looking for an optimized way of checking for any duplicates in a Panda dataframe column, but excluding a given position in every element of that column.
In the example there is a duplication in 'id1_ver1_ready' if we exclude the version number ('id1_ver1_ready' <-> 'id1_ver3_ready'). Same for ( 'id5_ver1_unknown' <-> 'id5_ver6_unknown')
from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['id1_ver1_ready', 'id2_ver1_unknown', 'id3_ver1_processed', 'id1_ver3_ready', 'id4_ver1_ready', 'id5_ver1_unknown', 'id5_ver6_unknown', 'id6_ver1_processed']})enter code here


Another possible solution, which filters df by removing duplicate entries based on the first and third parts of the ID column:

The str.split('_', expand=True) method splits the ID strings at the underscores into separate columns, resulting in a dataframe where each part of the ID is in its own column.

The duplicated([0, 2]) method then identifies rows that have the same values in the first (index 0) and third (index 2) columns, marking duplicates as True.

The tilde ~ operator negates this boolean mask, so the entire expression returns only the rows of df that have unique combinations of values in the first and third parts of the ID.


df[~df['ID'].str.split('_', expand=True).duplicated([0,2])]

Output:
                   ID
0      id1_ver1_ready
1    id2_ver1_unknown
2  id3_ver1_processed
4      id4_ver1_ready
5    id5_ver1_unknown
7  id6_ver1_processed


This is pretty compact and does exactly wht I need - awesome, many hanks !

Welcome, @Saly07!

# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['id1_ver1_ready', 'id2_ver1_unknown', 'id3_ver1_processed', 'id1_ver3_ready', 'id4_ver1_ready', 'id5_ver1_unknown', 'id5_ver6_unknown', 'id6_ver1_processed']
})

# Remove version from ID
df['ID_base'] = df['ID'].str.extract(r'([^_]+)_.*_(.*)', expand=False).fillna('').sum(axis=1)

# Check for duplicates
df['is_duplicate'] = df.duplicated('ID_base', keep=False)

print(df[df['is_duplicate']])

This snippet creates a new column ID_base by using a regular expression to extract parts of the ID, ignoring the version segment, and then checks for duplicates using this new column.

While a regex works for this problem, you can also remove the char(s) by position:
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['id1_ver1_ready', 'id2_ver1_unknown', 'id3_ver1_processed', 'id1_ver3_ready', 'id4_ver1_ready', 'id5_ver1_unknown', 'id5_ver6_unknown', 'id6_ver1_processed']})

# replace the char with a placeholder
df['ID_mod'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x[:2] + "_" + x[3:])

# Check for duplicates in the modified column
duplicates = df[df.duplicated('ID_mod', keep=False)]


Very good hint :) thanks for it!
